# How can I replace a jQuery object with an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$(".do").on("click", function(){
  var stuffs_html = "",
      num         = 2;
  $staffs_container = $(".staffs_container").clone().removeClass("hide_staffs_container");
  for ( var i = 0; i < num; i++){
      stuffs_html += $staffs_container;
  }

  $(".staffs_container").replaceWith(stuffs_html);
})
```

```css
.hide_staffs_container{
  display: none;
}

input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="staffs_container hide_staffs_container">
      <input  class="staff_name"  type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name" />
      <input  class="staff_mobile"  type="text" name="mobile" required placeholder="mobile" />
      <hr />
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" class="do" value="click" />
```

As you can see, it shows `[object]` instead of the HTML. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element objects and jQuery collections don't automatically output their markup when they're converted to strings (by `+=`, in this case). However, you don't necessarily need them to be strings.

You can build up a collection (array) of element objects, which you can then provide to `.replaceWith()` at once. You'll need to make more clones, though.

```js
$(".do").on("click", function(){
  var stuffs = [],
      num    = 2;

  var $staffs_container = $(".staffs_container.hide_staffs_container");

  for ( var i = 0; i < num; i++){
      stuffs.push(
          $staffs_container.clone().removeClass("hide_staffs_container")
      );
  }

  $(".staffs_container").replaceWith(stuffs);
})
```

```css
.hide_staffs_container{
  display: none;
}

input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="staffs_container hide_staffs_container">
      <input  class="staff_name"  type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name" />
      <input  class="staff_mobile"  type="text" name="mobile" required placeholder="mobile" />
      <hr />
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" class="do" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert each item to html with this loc

```
 $staffs_container.html();
```

and also first empty the parent div, then append children to it

```
$(".staffs_container").removeClass("hide_staffs_container").empty().append(stuffs_html);
```

```js
$(".do").on("click", function() {
var stuffs_html = "",
    num = 2;
  $staffs_container = $(".staffs_container").clone();
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    stuffs_html += $staffs_container.html();
  }
  console.log(stuffs_html)
  $(".staffs_container").removeClass("hide_staffs_container").empty().append(stuffs_html);
})
```

```css
.hide_staffs_container {
  display: none;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="staffs_container hide_staffs_container">
  <input class="staff_name" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name" />
  <input class="staff_mobile" type="text" name="mobile" required placeholder="mobile" />
  <hr />
</div>

<input type="button" class="do" value="click" />
```

Comment: Note: `.html()` returns the innerHTML, which won't include the markup for the `.staffs_container` element itself.

Answer (score 0):

`$staffs_container[0]` contains the `HTMLElement`, grab it then use `.outerHTML` to get the HTML string

```js
$(".do").on("click", function(){
  var stuffs_html = "",
      num         = 2;
  $staffs_container = $(".staffs_container")
                        .clone()
                        .removeClass("hide_staffs_container");
  for ( var i = 0; i < num; i++){
      stuffs_html += $staffs_container[0].outerHTML;
  }

  $(".staffs_container").replaceWith(stuffs_html);
})
```

```css
.hide_staffs_container{
  display: none;
}

input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="staffs_container hide_staffs_container">
      <input  class="staff_name"  type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name" />
      <input  class="staff_mobile"  type="text" name="mobile" required placeholder="mobile" />
      <hr />
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" class="do" value="click" />
```

Comment: Note: `.html()` returns the innerHTML, which won't include the markup for the `.staffs_container` element itself.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Well I also want `<div class="staffs_container`. Should I use `outterHTML` then?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated you code..I think you expecting like this.

```
 $(".do").on("click", function(){
  var stuffs_html = "",
  num         = 2;
  $staffs_container = 
  $(".staffs_container").clone().removeClass("hide_staffs_container"); 
  for ( var i = 0; i < num; i++){
   stuffs_html += $staffs_container.html();
  }  
  $(".staffs_container").replaceWith($staffs_container);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pf455/769/